# Convert lambda string expression to Func<string, string> error: "No property or field 'v' exists in type 'String'"

Tags: c#, lambda, func

I want to convert a string lambda expression to Func, but i have the following error: "No property or field 'v' exists in type 'String'".

```
var func = System.Linq.Dynamic.DynamicExpression.ParseLambda<string, string>("v => v.ToLower()").Compile();

var outputValue = func(inputValue);
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The parameter is implicit, and is called `it`:

```
var func = System.Linq.Dynamic.DynamicExpression.ParseLambda<string, string>(
    "it.ToLower()").Compile();
```

This fact doesn't appear to be documented, but assuming this is [System.Linq.Dynamic](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Linq.Dynamic/), note that despite the `System.*` namespace, this does *not* appear to be a Microsoft-owned library.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, that worked! Yes you are right that's not a Microsoft-owned library, and [System.Linq.Dynamic/wiki](https://github.com/kahanu/System.Linq.Dynamic/wiki) documentation don't have that reference (or maybe i have missed something).

Comment: @Murplatina found it from there: https://github.com/kahanu/System.Linq.Dynamic/wiki/Dynamic-Expressions - `it` is mentioned

Comment: Yes i have missed that, here is the answer: [current-instance](https://github.com/kahanu/System.Linq.Dynamic/wiki/Dynamic-Expressions#current-instance).